# Use Vuforia and io.realm db crash the app

Tags: android, realm, vuforia

I am having trouble using the SDK-Vuforia 5.0.5 with [io.realm](https://realm.io/) data pack.
When attempting to boot the Vuforia the app this closing and displays the following error in the line of LogCat:

> W/System.err﹕ The library libVuforia.so could not be loaded

By removing the following line in gradle the application runs smoothly:

> compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2+'

Comment: It is strange that loading one `.so` file will make loading another fail. How do you include Vuforia in your project?

Comment: @geisshirt, I used the steps mentioned here:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/using-android-studio-vuforia

Recalling that the Vufuria runs smoothly for Gradle remove the compile the io.realm

Comment: Does vuforia only have .so for armeabi-v7a? And which device are you using to test this problem? There might be a chance if you are using x86 devices, and the system didn't copy vufora's so while installing since the priority is x86 lib first, and Realm has it.

Comment: My project has the following structure to the folder of Vuforia app> main> jniLibs> armeabi-v7a> libVuforia.so
Testo on a Galaxy S6, to remove the realm compile the Vuforia starts without problems, add the line of the realm compile the gradle presents the error mentioned.

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy S6 features Cortex-A53 and Cortex-A57 i.e., ARMv8. These CPUs have ARMv7 support but I guess that Realm will load the ARMv8 `.so` file. I'm not sure how mixing ARMv7 and ARMv8 `.so` works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit libraries which is what is happening here. The proper solution would be to ask Vuforia to provide 64-bit binaries. Until then I am afraid you will manually have to edit the Realm jar file and remove the 64-bit `.so` files.

Answer (score 0):

just put this into your app build.gradle defaultConfig {} section:

```
 ndk {   
   abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a"  
 }
```